# Trying to convert a char array to integer array in Java with this code

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert an array of characters into integers, so I can get the ascii code, but the code I have doesn't seem to be working.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Encrypt {


public static void main(String[] args) {

String phrase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter phrase to be messed with ");
char[] charArray = phrase.toCharArray();

for (int count = 0; count < charArray.length; count++) {
int digit = ((int)charArray[count]);

System.out.println(digit[count]);

}




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly cast it. You may simply assign it to int.  Refer [5.1.2. Widening Primitive Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

Example:

```
 char[] charArray = "test".toCharArray();

        for (int count = 0; count < charArray.length; count++) {
            int digit = charArray[count];

            System.out.println(digit);

        }
```

output:

```
116
101
115
116
```

Answer (score 2):

`digit` is an `int` type primitive variable can't be treated as an array

```
digit[count])
```

just use

```
digit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way...

```
char[] charArray = phrase.toCharArray();

int[] intArray = new int[charArray.length];

int i=0;

for (char c : charArray){

      intArray[i] = c;
      i++;

}
```